# How to enable Android ViewBinding just for certain XML files instead of whole project files

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I want to enable Android View Binding but just for certain XML files. If I enable ViewBinding in the project then the entire XML files are parsed and converted to code, as I have a very large number of XML files, it would increase build times and apk size quite a lot I suppose.
Also disabling binding in every file XML is tedious!
Is there an option to activate ViewBinding and then enable it in the files we want?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with View Binding, you would have to use Data Binding for this which has all the goodies of View Binding but only applies to layouts you give the  tag to.

Not entirely sure if this is 100% a solution for you but here's a link! https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Comment: Just tested this and I think it's a good solution. I can enable view Binding via data Binding as I go and maybe use data binding.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, It is not possible, when you enable view binding, it gets enabled for the whole project. But if you are worried about generated code by view binding, increasing your app size then you should use Proguard for shrinking and obfuscating your code. It will remove all unused code from the build which is not used in the app.

Read more about obfuscating and shrinking apk https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code